# Django Form not posting due to TinyMCE removing name

Tags: javascript, python, django, tinymce

I'm trying to post my textarea. Without the TinyMCE RichText, the form posts. However, when adding the RichText it seems the iframe removes the name from the textarea called 'description'.

I'm aware that TinyMCE isn't a textarea, it's an iframe. When I submit, the 'description' is missing. Is there anyway to post and grab the 'description' data for the backend? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        width: "100%"
});

...


<div>
    <label for="id_description">Description</label>
    <textarea class="required input-text full-width" id="id_description" rows="4" name="description"></textarea>
</div>
```

What worked before in my views.py:

```
description = request.POST.get('description','')
..and more stuff
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use this package: [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce), install it ([django-tinymce docs](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/))
and declare form field (for model text field) as fallow:

```
description = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}), required=False, label="Description")
```

Comment: This is really good to know, thank you. I'll try installing. I realized that I have another form(on another page) where it's working perfectly. I just don't understand why this one isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

On submit you may use

```
tinymce.get('description').getContent();
```

to get the editor content.
Optionally you may call tinymce.triggerSave() - which should update your textarea with the editor content.

`tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` will only work if you are using one single editor and it has been clicked into!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content using `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()`

Comment: He is asking to get the content of textarea in the view (controller)